# How do I create a table which has values defined by the output of a "for" loop in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm currently writing an Addon for World of Warcraft, but I've run a bit of a basic lua problem. The gist of it is, I want to reduce the following elements inside this `for` loop into a single line.

Currently, I am using WoW's api command of `"SetAlpha(0)"` (which just hides the frame in game) on a list of frames that share the same name except for the number at the end. `ActionButton1Name, ActionButton2Name, ActionButton3Name, etc`.

I also have to do the same thing to four other lists, each also having 12 different versions of themselves `MultiBarBottomRightButton1Name, MultiBarBottomRightButton2Name, etc`.

Essentially, I'd like to take what I currently have:

```
for i=1, 12 do
    ["ActionButton"..i.."Name"]:SetAlpha(0)
    ["MultiBarBottomRightButton"..i.."Name"]:SetAlpha(0)
    ["MultiBarBottomLeftButton"..i.."Name"]:SetAlpha(0)
    ["MultiBarRightButton"..i.."Name"]:SetAlpha(0)
    ["MultiBarLeftButton"..i.."Name"]:SetAlpha(0)
end
```

*SetAlpha is specific to World of Warcraft's API, so disregard that as needed.*

And transform it into something where I have all the [ ] elements in their own table somewhere else, and then later use that index

```
local buttonNameIndex = function()
    for i=1, 12 do 
        ["ActionButton"..i.."Name"]
        ["MultiBarBottomRightButton"..i.."Name"]
        ["MultiBarBottomLeftButton"..i.."Name"]
        ["MultiBarRightButton"..i.."Name"]
        ["MultiBarLeftButton"..i.."Name"] 
    end
end

for i,v in ipairs(buttonNameIndex) do
v:SetAlpha(0) end
```

However, the above function didn't seem to work, in that the terminal was spitting out an error of having an unexpected symbol near the `do` of the 2nd line.

As to why I'd like to do this: I'll be doing a lot more with that list of frames later on, so it'd be nice to have them all combined into a single table.

Comment: If these are global variables, use `_G["ActionButton"..i.."Name"]:SetAlpha(0)`.

Comment: Yep, whoops, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If these are global variables, use expressions like this:

```
_G["ActionButton"..i.."Name"]:SetAlpha(0)
```

which access a global variable from a dynamically created name.